# Automatic detection of relations between workspace variables through functions

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to write a function what detect this relation between the variables I have got in the workspace:

```
v1 - fft(v2) = 0
```

Where v1, v2 are variables of my workspace.

Sometimes I need to know which variables have a certain numerical relation. If I have thirty, I don´t want to be looking for this relation in "manual way", just introducing a sentence for each pair of different variables.

I would like a function in which I introduce (or I modify this function every time I need it) the sentence (for instance what I wrote before) and the function show me the pair of variables a I am looking for.
Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [who()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/who.html?BB=1) to programatically obtain a list of variables that currently exist.  You can then use [eval()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/eval.html) to get their values.  At that point, you can use a fairly trivial nested loop to iterate over all possible pairs, looking for that relationship.

**Note 1:** Using `eval()` for "normal" programming is considered bad style; it should only really be used for meta-programming tasks like this.

**Note 2:** If you have `N` variables in the workspace, there are `N^2` ordered pairs.  This may take a while to iterate over if `N` is large.

**Note 3:** You're essentially looking for equality between variables, which may not be particularly reliable in floating-point.

Comment: About Note 3, I am aware of that, but I could put something like: average(v1-fft(v2))<= 10^(-3). Of course the expression I mentioned is for a particular thing I´m doing now but the expression could be whatever thing. Thank you for your response.