# Create a vector of the workspace variables name

Tags: matlab, variables, vector, workspace

Related with a question I asked before [MATLAB: Automatic detection of relations between workspace variables through functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612170/matlab-automatic-detection-of-relations-between-workspace-variables-through-func).
Does any knows how can I get a vector with conteins the variable names of the workspace variables?
Thank you.

Comment: In the previous post this question was already answered, why are you asking again?

Comment: Oh Sorry, apparently I didn´t realice of that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MATLAB: Automatic detection of relations between workspace variables through functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612170/matlab-automatic-detection-of-relations-between-workspace-variables-through-func)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try:

```
variables_list = who;
```

However be aware that this might create a new variable `variables_list` if it did not exist prior to this command and that in this case the string `'variables_list'` will not be in the list. You should also be careful with the special `ans` variable which might or might not show up, depending on your coding style. For the kind of things you want to do, you might try to combine this with `evalin` to get the list of variables of another workspace.

NB: Technically `variables_list`is not a vector but a cell array.

Hope this helps.

A.