# Loopin through all the structures in a workspace

Tags: matlab, for-loop, structure

I have 40 structures in my Workspace which are divided into three different categories i.e. a map, a table and a constant. How can i Loop through all the structures at once and then differentiate it on their types and perform certain operations on them?

Comment: In a first step you can use `who` and `whose` to get an overview over your workspace variables. What do you mean by "structure"? Variables of a certain type? Or `struct` variables only?

Comment: In a second step you can use the `class` returned by `whos` (`whose` above was a typo) to determine the data type or to sort this list. And in another step you could use `eval` (see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/4613158/1627585).

Comment: How does this differ from [your question yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35342983/directional-derivatives-of-a-matrix)?